# Intuition behind a conditional expectation in a Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Earthquakes occur according to a Poisson process with $\lambda = 5$ per year, let $T_1$ be the time of the first occurrence of the process and we wish to figure out what is the average time that will pass until we reach a period of 3 months without any earthquakes.

So, if we define $X$ as the random variable which describes the time until we get a period of 3 months without earthquakes we have that:

\begin{align*}
E[X] &= E\left[X|T_1 > \frac{1}{4}\right]\cdot P \left\{ T_1 > \frac{1}{4}\right\} + E\left[X|T_1 \leq \frac{1}{4}\right]\cdot P \left\{ T_1 \leq \frac{1}{4}\right\}\\
&=0 + E\left[X|T_1 \leq \frac{1}{4}\right]\cdot P \left\{ T_1 \leq \frac{1}{4}\right\}
\end{align*}

According to my notes, $E\left[X|T_1 \leq \frac{1}{4}\right] = E\left[T_1|T_1 < \frac{1}{4}\right] + E[X]$.

Can someone please explain why the previous equality holds and what is the intuition behind it?

Comment: How do you conclude $E[X|T_1>1/4]=0$? Wouldn't its value be $1/4$?

Comment: I agree with the last part as that is just re-starting the same experiment when $T_1$ fails to be longer than $1/4$. You could also condition on all possible values of $T_1$: $$E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} E[X|T_1=t]f_{T_1}(t)dt$$ and of course $\int_0^{\infty} = \int_0^{1/4} + \int_{1/4}^{\infty}$.

Comment: @Michael I believe it's because given that the first earthquake took longer than 3 months to occur then the expected value of the time we have to wait until a period of 3 months without earthquakes is zero - since it has already happened.

Comment: Well, I suppose my understanding of the definition of $X$ is always 3 months larger than your understanding of the definition of $X$.  Regardless of either way of defining $X$, the second part is unchanged since if $T_1$ fails, we add the value of the (failed) $T_1$ to the time we wait, then try again.

Comment: Maybe I didn't specify it clearly, but $X$ denotes the time until the 3 month period begins meaning that if we didn't get any earthquakes on the first 3 months we didn't have to wait for the period to begin. Regarding the second part I believe I'm starting to get it. Thanks for the comment!